# Cypher query for list pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a schema which looks like below:

1. A `customer` is linked to another `customer` with a relationship `SIMILAR` having `similarity score`.

   Example: `(c1:Customer)-->(c2:Customer)`
2. An `Email` node is connected to each `customer` with relationship `MAIL_AT` with the following node properties:

```
 {
     "active_email_address": "a@mail.com",
     "cibil_email_addresses": [
         "b@mail.com", "c@mail.com"
     ]
 }
```

Example: `(e1:Email)<-[:MAIL_AT]-(c1:Customer)-[:SIMILAR]->(c2:Customer)-[:MAIL_AT]->(e2:Email)`

3. A `Risk` node with some risk-related properties (below) and is related to `customer` with relationship `HAS_RISK`:

```
  {
    "f0_score": 870.0,
    "pta_score": 430.0
  }
```

4. A `Fraud` node with some fraud-related properties (below) and is related to `customer` with relationship `IS_FRAUD`:

```
  {
    "has_commited_fraud": true
  }
```

**My Objectives**:

1. To find the customers with common email addresses (irrespective of active and secondary)?

**My tentative solution:**

```
MATCH (email:Email)
WITH email.cibil_email_addresses + email.active_email_address AS emailAddress, email
UNWIND emailAddress AS eaddr
WITH DISTINCT eaddr AS deaddr, email
UNWIND deaddr AS eaddress
MATCH (customer:Customer)-[]->(someEmail:Email)
WHERE eaddress IN someEmail.cibil_email_addresses + someEmail.active_email_address
WITH eaddress, COLLECT(customer.customer_id) AS customers
RETURN eaddress, customers
```

**Problem:** It is taking forever to execute this. Working with lists will take time I understand, however, I'm flexible to change the schema (If suggested). Should I break the email address into separate nodes? If yes, then how do I break `cibil_email_addresses` into different nodes as they can vary - *Should I create two nodes with different `cibil email addresses` and connect both of them to customer with relationship `HAS_CIBIL_EMAIL`? (Is this a valid schema design)*. Also, it is possible, a customer's `active_email_address` is present in other customer's `cibil_email_address`. I'm trying to find a synthetic identity attack. PS: If there exists some `APOC` that can help achieve this and below, do suggest with example.

2. In production, for a given customer with `email addresses`, `risk values`, `similarity score`, and also given other customers may or may not be tagged with `fraud_status`, I want to check whether this new person will fall in a fraud ring or not. PS: If I need to use any `gds` to solve this, please suggest with examples.
3. If I were to do this same exercise with some other node such as `Address` which may be partially matching and will be having same list of historical addresses in a list, what should be my ideal approach?

I know, I'm tagging someone in my question, but that person only seems to be active with respect to Cypher on StackOverflow. **@cybersam** any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (e:Email)
UNWIND (e.cibil_email_addresses + e.active_email_address) AS address
WITH address, COLLECT(e) AS es
UNWIND es AS email
MATCH (email)<-[:MAIL_AT]-(cust)
RETURN address, COLLECT(cust) AS customers
```

The `WITH` clause takes advantage of the [arregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` to automatically collect all the `Email` nodes containing the same address, using `address` as the grouping key.

*You should only ask one question at a time. You have a couple of other questions at the bottom. If you continue to need help with them, please create new questions.*